# How do I get config preferences for a cordova plugin/project using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is there any way to get config preferences for a cordova plugin/project using Javascript?

I inspected the code of various cordova modules but I couldn't find any public API.

I also looked at the `window.cordova` object. Nothing.

Can you help, please?

Comment: What *config preferences* are you interested in? Those of the `config.xml` file? (description, author, ...)

Comment: `<preference name="" />`

Comment: Have you tried something like `document.getElementsByTagName("preference")[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Readymade plugin is available in the following [git repo](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) for certain predefined preferences like app name, version no and version code.

But if you are looking to get these values in android, iOS or browser, check out this [link](https://taivo.github.io/guides/read-config-xml-in-cordova) which gives more info